# PHP 7.2 says Yaz functions are undefined

Tags: php, z39.50

I have installed yaz library (see phpinfo below). The yaz.so is in the proper extension folder, it shows up in my phpinfo (see below).

Yet when I attempt to use any of the functions, php says undefined.

What am I missing?

From phpInfo()

```
PHP Version 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
---------
yaz
YAZ Support enabled
PHP/YAZ Version 1.2.2
YAZ Version 4.2.30
Compiled with YAZ version   4.2.30
```

Comment: Don't know alot about YAZ but are you sure these versions are up to date and compatible with your PHP version?

Comment: This looks like the output from the CLI version. How about checking phpinfo() for the Apache/FPM version of PHP? There's different php.ini's usually.

Comment: @mario. This phpinfo is from an actual php file running from the web interface. I don't think I have fpm enabled on this server. I only have 2 php.ini files on the server, apache and cli. This is from the apache file.

Comment: @Isaac - I guess that is my main problem, do I have the right version. The install process actually did a compile (I think successfully?)

Comment: SOLVED. Thanks to @mario's suggestions, I checked both php.ini files and discovered that my cli/php.ini did not have the extension installed. I am testing my functions from the command line, the reason for my previous errors. Now working. Thanks.